# Sidebar Fleur-de-lis Formatting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

I noticed a small design issue with the tag box where "Favorite Tags" and "Ignored Tags" are located. The fleur-de-lis on the side is directly underneath the first two letters on both labels, which makes it hard to read (not to mention it looks pretty bad). For the other boxes,  the labels are centered. I would suggest doing that in this case or adding a left padding to move the letters away from the fleur-de-lis design.

[image]

Comment: Sharing a screenshot would help. Also, what browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Using Chrome on Windows 7. Screenshot added.

Comment: Same for me in Firefox 12 on XP. And (I believe) FF15 on Win 7. And that box in Meta is the same, too.

Comment: My mistake: it's Firefox 19 under Windows 7.

Comment: I see the behavior on meta, but not on the main site....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed on live server.

Comment: What does "fixed on live server" mean? It still looks the same to me (FF19/Win7), even after a hard refresh.

Comment: Looks good for me on Chrome.

Comment: However, it is still doing it on meta.

Comment: @Ben oops I missed meta. it will be fixed after our next build.

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross can you try hard refresh on the main site now? we just purged the server caching.

Answer (score 1):

Safari on Mac does not show this problem.

[image]